# I created a Python package using poetry, I published it to PyPI, but my package description is missing in PyPI

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I created a Python package using poetry
Then I published my package to PyPI using poetry build, poetry publish, but my package description is missing in PyPI.

The project is hosted in GitHub: https://github.com/fsistemas/sql2json.

Project in PyPI without description: https://pypi.org/project/sql2json

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the [`readme` configuration option](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#readme) is missing in the `[tool.poetry]` section of the project's `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: @FranciscoPérez Does that answer your question, or is there still something in need of clarification?